# Can I Use a Docker Container for Experimenting Things instead of a Hypervisor?

Tags: linux, virtual-machine, docker

I want to have access to a lightweight Linux distro with shell functionality. It should be able to connect to the Internet and download packages.

I'm already on Ubuntu 19.04 and my machine won't be able to function properly if I install a virtual machine. I've noticed all this fuss about docker and how lightweight it is.

So, my question is can I perhaps, get a full-fledged distro(preferably Arch) running inside a container? If possible, how should I go about it?

**PS:** I want to experiment with malware and stuff. And looking for a lightweight solution that allows me to get rid of the system whenever I want.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've figured this out. It's **very much possible**. I'll be adding the procedure later so that people like me can get this information faster in the future.